# Where to store API keys for React/Node app in aws ec2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, api-key

I have a react/node application in an ec2 ubuntu instance(sitting at /home/ubuntu/app-name). It's consistently deployed using AWS Cloud deploy and Bitbucket pipelines. I have some API KEYS that I need to use in the application, but I do not want to store them in my repo. Where can I keep these keys and fetch when I need them?

Comment: Is the whole EC2 instance deployed and the old one is terminated, or its same EC2 instance and you deploy only new version of app?

Comment: @libik same ec3 instance, a different version of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case I would recommend the AWS EC2 Parameter Store. Launch the EC2 instance with an instance profile that permits access to the credentials in the Parameter Store and fetch the keys using the AWS SDK of the language of your choice, or using the AWS CLI (e.g. when bootstrapping the instance in the instance user data).

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) in AWS. AWS Secrets Manager helps you protect secrets needed to access your applications, services, and IT resources. The service enables you to easily rotate, manage, and retrieve database credentials, API keys, and other secrets throughout their lifecycle.

Here's the best article which resembles your criteria.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-to-aws-secrets-manager-service-within-a-virtual-private-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with AWS EC2 Parameter Store. Out of the two options, they both accomplish the same thing (there are slight differences). For my goal, the parameter store would accomplish it the same and it's free compared to, at the time of this writing, you are charged per secret per month for using AWS Secret Manager.